# Implementing LayoutAlgorithm.SINGLE_COLUMN algorithm?

Tags: android, css, webview

I need to display the html content as in gmail app showing the message content with more readability.

The first step I tried is applying custom and common css to all the message contents. But it did not respond well for media queries and it varied among variety of contents. Moreover image was not in right proportions.

So I decided to use LayoutAlgorithm.SINGLE_COLUMN. It works exactly as I expected for lower devices except for multi column tables. But for devices > ktikat, it appears to be deprecated.

Is there any other ways that I can implement LayoutAlgorithm.SINGLE_COLUMN algorithm? Or is there any alternates? Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

[word-wrapping no longer supported](http://www.androidpolice.com/2014/01/28/bug-watch-text-reflow-removed-from-webviews-in-kitkat-probably-not-coming-back/)

In Android 4.4(Kitkat) onwards with the integration of chromium, Text reflow is removed from web views .

There are discussions on forums where this issue is being discussed and it has got replies like this issue has been declared  "Working As Intended" and a project member has clearly stated that there are no plans to change course.

This is what is mentioned:

"Calling this a bug might be a bit inaccurate - it seems like Google intended to remove text reflow. Maybe the search giant really is tired of waiting on web developers to support mobile devices and decided to be more aggressive about it. Perhaps this is just a precursor to Google introducing an improved and more intelligent algorithm. After all, the method of forcing content into a single narrow column was a bit hack-ish and prone to its own set of bad behaviors. Whatever the case may be, besides hoping for a quick turnaround from the greater world of web development, there isn't much we can do".

Answer (score 0):

You can process your pages using Google Mobilizer service, which applies a lot of simplifying transformations to the content. For example: http://www.google.com/gwt/x?u=http://cnn.com/

Answer (score 0):

As you know, the SINGLE_COLUMN Algorithm will apply some styles to the given html page to place the html contents in a single column. So, we can change the style properties of an html page by injecting CSS to the `<head/>` section of the loaded html page. Steps included are,

1. Download the html source programmatically and store in as a `String` object.
2. Inject your css style to the html page. ie, you have to prepare an css style that will override all the other styles on the html page.
3. In your java code , inject the CSS to the downloaded html string by calling `injectCssToHtmlCode()` and then load the returned htmlString to the webview.

   //bufferHtmlString  has the html source code
           webView.loadData(injectCssToHtmlCode(bufferHtmlString.toString()), "text/html", "utf-8");
4. The method `injectCssToHtmlCode()`,

```js
 private String injectCssToHtmlCode(String downloadedHtmlCode) {
  String head = "<head><meta name='viewport' "+
    "content='initial-scale=1.0, "+
    "maximum-scale=1.0, "+
    "minimum-scale=1.0, "+
    "height=device-height, "+
    "width=device-width, "+
    "target-densityDpi=device-dpi' /> "+
    "  <style type='text/css'> "+                                                                     
    " html.body {width:50% !important;  height:auto !important;  max-width:100% !important; } "+

" body {word-break:break-all !important;  margin:0px !important;  padding:2px !important; }"+
" h1 {max-width:100% !important;  height:auto !important;  margin:1px 0px !important;  padding:2px 0px !important;   }"+                                      
" h2 {max-width:100% !important;  height:auto !important;  margin:1px 0px !important;  padding:2px 0px !important; } "+                                     
" h3 {max-width:100% !important;  height:auto !important;  margin:1px 0px !important;  padding:2px 0px !important; } "+                                     
" h4 {max-width:100% !important;  height:auto !important;  margin:1px 0px !important;  padding:2px 0px !important; } "+                                     
" h5 {max-width:100% !important;  height:auto !important;  margin:1px 0px !important;  padding:2px 0px !important; } "+                                     
" h6 {max-width:100% !important;  height:auto !important;  margin:1px 0px !important;  padding:2px 0px !important; } "+                                     
" hr {max-width:100% !important;  height:auto !important;  margin-left:0px !important;  margin-right:0px !important;  padding:1px !important;  border:none}"+                                      

" p {max-width:100% !important;  height:auto !important;  margin:1px 0px !important;  padding:2px 0px !important;  width:100% !important; word-wrap: break-word !important;} "+                                  
" pre {max-width:100% !important;  height:auto !important;  margin:1px 0px !important;  padding:2px 0px !important;  white-space:pre-wrap !important; }"+                                      
" form {max-width:100% !important;  height:auto !important;  margin:1px 0px !important;  padding:2px 0px !important; width:100% !important; word-wrap: break-word !important;} "+                                     

" dl {max-width:100% !important;  height:auto !important;  margin:1px 0px !important;  padding:2px 0px !important; width:100% !important; word-wrap: break-word !important;} "+                                     
" ul {max-width:100% !important;  height:auto !important;  margin:1px 0px !important;  padding:2px 0px 1em !important; width:100% !important; word-wrap: break-word !important;} "+                                     
" ol {max-width:100% !important;  height:auto !important;  margin:1px 0px !important;  padding:2px 0px 1.5em !important; width:100% !important; word-wrap: break-word !important;}"+                                      
" dir {max-width:100% !important;  height:auto !important;  margin:1px 0px !important;  padding:2px 0px !important; width:100% !important; word-wrap: break-word !important;}  "+                                    
" div {max-width:100% !important;  height:auto !important;  margin:1px 0px !important;  padding:2px 0px !important;  background-color:#FF0055   !important;  width:100% !important; word-wrap: break-word !important;} "+                                     

" marquee {max-width:100% !important;  height:auto !important;  margin:1px 0px !important;  padding:2px 0px !important; } "+                                     
" table {max-width:100% !important;  height:auto !important;  margin:1px 0px !important;  padding:2px 0px !important;   word-wrap: break-word !important;}"+ 
" table input[type='text'] {max-width:100% !important;  height:auto !important;  margin:1px 0px !important;  padding:2px 0px !important;  width:100% !important; word-wrap: break-word !important;}"+                                      
" table input[type='file'] {max-width:100% !important;  height:auto !important;  margin:1px 0px !important;  padding:2px 0px !important;  width:100% !important; word-wrap: break-word !important;}"+                                      
" table textarea {max-width:100% !important;  height:auto !important;  margin:1px 0px !important;  padding:2px 0px !important;  width:100% !important; word-wrap: break-word !important;} "+

" tr {max-width:100% !important;  height:auto !important;  margin:1px 0px !important;  padding:2px 0px !important;   word-wrap: break-word !important;} "+                                     
" td {max-width:100% !important;  height:auto !important;  margin:1px 0px !important;  padding:2px 0px !important;   word-wrap: break-word !important;} "+                                     
" input {max-width:100% !important;  height:auto !important;  margin:1px 0px !important;  padding:2px 0px !important; word-wrap: break-word !important;} "+                                     
" textarea {max-width:100% !important;  height:auto !important;  margin:1px 0px !important;  padding:2px 0px !important; word-wrap: break-word !important;}"+                                      
                                     
" select {max-width:100% !important;  height:auto !important;  margin:1px 0px !important;  padding:2px 0px !important; }  "+                                    
" a {max-width:100% !important;  height:auto !important;  margin:1px 0px !important;  padding:2px 0px !important; word-wrap: break-word !important;} "+                                     
" object {max-width:100% !important;  height:auto !important;  margin:1px 0px !important;  padding:2px 0px !important; }"+                                      
" img {max-width:100% !important;  margin:1px 0px !important;  padding:2px 0px !important; }   "+                                   
" marquee[behavior='alternate'] {display:block !important;  overflow:-webkit-marquee !important;  max-width:100% !important;  -webkit-marquee-style:alternate !important; } "+                                     
" .wb{word-break:break-all !important; } "+

" @-webkit-keyframes blink { "+                                     
"   0% { opacity: 0 }   "+                                   
"   50% { opacity: 0 }  "+                                    
"   50.01% { opacity: 1 }  100% { opacity: 1 }"+                                      
" }           "+                           
" blink {     "+                                 
"   -webkit-animation: blink 0.7s infinite linear alternate !important;  "+                                     
"   -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased !important;       "+                                
" }     "+                                 

"</style></head>";
  return "<html>" + head + "<body>" + downloadedHtmlCode + "</body></html>";
 }
```

Comment: sorry pal. This css does not fit for all types of content